# Showing geometric distribution is almost surely finite

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $T \sim Geom(\rho)$, for some $\rho \in (0,1]$ . I would like to show that $\Bbb P(T<\infty)=1$, i.e $T$ is almost surely finite.

Here's how I tackle this problem:

Since CDF of Geometric distribution, denoted $F_x$ is equivalent to $\Bbb P(T \leq x)$ . So if I take the limit ($x \rightarrow \infty$), then

$F_x=\mathbb P(T\leqslant x) = 1 - (1-p)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Hence $T$ is almost surely finite. Is this legitimate?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb P(T < \infty) = \mathbb P( \exists_k T = k) = \sum_k \mathbb P(T=k)$. Can you show this is $1$?

Comment: @DominikKutek what does $\mathbb P( \exists_k T = k)$ mean?

Comment: What is your definition of geometric distribution? It looks to me that this statement is true by definition...

Comment: You should have $\mathbb P(T\leqslant x) = 1 - (1-p)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ but otherwise the basic idea is correct.

Comment: @Math1000 is it correct now?

Comment: I meant: $\mathbb P( \exists_k : T=k) = \mathbb P( \bigcup_{k} \{ T= k\} )$ and because those events $\{T=k\}$ are disjoint, we have $\sum_k \mathbb P(T=k) = \sum_{k=0} p(1-p)^k = p \frac{1}{1 - (1-p)} = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(x<\infty) = \sum_{t\in \mathbb{N}}{P(x=t)}=\sum_{t\in \mathbb{N}}{(1-p)^{t-1}\cdot p=p \cdot \sum_{t\in \mathbb{N}}{(1-p)^{t-1}}}$

The above can be calculated as a sum of infinity Geometric series:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a\cdot q^k}$ for $0<q<1$ as in our case we get $\frac{a}{1-q}$

In our case $p \cdot \sum_{t\in \mathbb{N}}{(1-p)^{t-1}}=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)}=\frac{p}{p}=1$